# Xubuntu and Lubuntu showing battery incorrectly

Tags: xubuntu, lubuntu, power-management, xfce, battery

I installed Lubuntu last week and currently I'm using Xubuntu. Neither of them is displaying the battery status correctly.

I used openbox and it showed up correctly.

When the battery is full, Xfce battery shows only max 55% while openbox shows 100%

Hardware is Macbook pro 13" early 2011

---

Correct in `acpi`:

[image: acpi command returns 98%]

Incorrect in xfce-power:

[image: fully charged (61%)]

Default of file capacity (61) and I can't edit it (Used `sudo nano` & `w !sudo tee %` in vim)

[image: file open in Vim contains only 61 and warns it is a readonly file]

How to fix?

Comment: Perhaps this helps you? http://askubuntu.com/questions/713687/how-to-make-upower-show-correct-battery-state

Comment: I do not see the solution?

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/634936/battery-indicator-on-macbookair-4-2-incorrect Then, perhaps this?